# how to edit the codes for the summary of R S4 Object?

Tags: r, object, summary, r-s4

I recently want to release a new pacakge with S4 objects. When i get the objects, the slots will be shown. The results list were too large. I would like to consult how to get the the summary of R S4 Object？

just list this:

objects

description information

xxxx
xxx

metaData
...

but not this:

objects

slot 1
slot 2
...

Thanks!
Hees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write methods for the functions `print`, `show` and `summary` if you want custom behaviour for your S4 objects. For example

```
## define a simple class for example purposes
myClass <- setClass("myclass",slots=c(x="numeric"))
## now write a method for the print method that uses my class
setMethod("print","myclass",function(x)cat("a myclass object with value ",x@x))
## make an example object
z <- myClass(x=1)
## now print it --- it uses the method defined above
print(z)
```

`show` is what gets called implicitly when you just type the name of the object at the command line. `print` and `summary` are usually called explicitly by the user.